# Rails 5 Fixtures - How to avoiding unique key constraints when using defaults?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automated-tests, ruby-on-rails-5, fixtures

Consider the fixture written below.

**Problem:** When executed, unique key constraint occurs when invalid_email_user is created.

**Reason:** Defaults are only executed once and when the second user is created, a unique index database constraint is violated.

By using $LABEL, I am able to avoid the unique constraint on email but this is not possible for a token generator method like in this case.

```
DEFAULTS: &DEFAULTS
  email: $LABEL@test.com
  authentication_token: <%= Devise.friendly_token %>

user:
  <<: *DEFAULTS

invalid_email_user:
  <<:*DEFAULTS
  email: test.com
```

There are several bypass here that I can think of:

1. Repeat the method for each user (but I want to keep it as DRY as possible)
2. Switch to FactoryGirl

However, these are not solutions that I am after since I'm trying out Rails 5 defaults. There must be something I'm missing since this is certainly a very common situation? Can I pass a block to a fixture like we do for FactoryGirl?

Comment: You can use dynamic fixtures with erb, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html . Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I am already using ERB in the code above @pascal-betz

Comment: I've seen that. But was referring to the loop:

```<% 1.upto(1000) do |i| %>
fix_<%= i %>:
  id: <%= i %>
  name: guy_<%= 1 %>
<% end %>```


Other than that: i think you are out of luck with fixtures. They are first processed through ERB and then read and ingested.
I don't see a problem with duplication though. I think it's good to have values that are different repeated.

Comment: @pascalbetz yeah, that's what I thought, hoping someone would have a better recommendation out there. I have already seen the example above earlier but couldn't think of an alternative past it. I guess its possible to use erb to generate a method, then constantly call the method to populate the code in yml? that seems possible